# After creating JAR file, command line returns 'Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleProgram`?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

JAR file will not run, instead returns

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleProgram
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ExampleProject/ExampleProgram (wrong name: ExampleProgram)
```

I've tried deleting the class file, then re-creating the JAR file. I've tried deleting and re-creating the program from scratch. I've tried creating the JAR file without a manifest.

```
package ExampleProject;

public class ExampleProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello, World!");

    }

}
```

This is the exact process in how I tried to create the JAR file on the command-line.

```
Josephs-MBP:program jepappano4$ ls
ExampleProgram.class    ExampleProgram.java
Josephs-MBP:program jepappano4$ java ExampleProgram
Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleProgram
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ExampleProject/ExampleProgram (wrong name: ExampleProgram)
Josephs-MBP:program jepappano4$ ls
ExampleProgram.class    ExampleProgram.java
Josephs-MBP:program jepappano4$ ls
ExampleProgram.class    ExampleProgram.java manifest.mf
Josephs-MBP:program jepappano4$ jar -cvfm myprogram.jar manifest.mf *.class
added manifest
adding: ExampleProgram.class(in = 450) (out= 301)(deflated 33%)
Josephs-MBP:program jepappano4$ java -jar myprogram.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ExampleProgram
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ExampleProject/ExampleProgram (wrong name: ExampleProgram)
```

I am following a tutorial on creating JAR files and I expected this process to work, but it doesn't. What am I doing incorrect here?

Not sure if this is important or not, however, I am using Java 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'wrong name' error is the key error here. This is what it means:

In java, the full name of a class is its package, followed by a dot, followed by the classname. So, your full name for this class is `ExampleProject.ExampleProgram`.

To start them, you must put this full name in yor manifest: It needs to have an entry that looks like:

```
Main-Class: ExampleProject.ExampleProgram
```

In addition, folder structure *must* match the dots. So, the jar file (which is really just a zip file) must contain inside it at the root level a directory named `ExampleProject` and this dir needs a file named `ExampleProgram.class`.

You've gotten one or both of those wrong, causing this error. You can check the structure of your jar file as follows:

```
jar tvf myjar.jar
```

you should see a listing for:

```
ExampleProject/ExampleProgram.class
```

in that precise location.